# Add menu item in XAMPP

Tags: menu, xampp, addition

I want to add a menu item in my xampp home page, right in the Demos category. I can see in here there are multiple items like CD Collection, Biorhythm, Guest Book etc..., I want to add my folder "Courses01" right before CD Collection.

How can I do that?

Here's where I want to place it [image: Adding a menu item in XAMPP]

[image: Something similar]

I forgot to mention, I saw this option in WAMP, I had a directory in /www folder and I could browse my directory from the browser, just click on the links. I want something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the folders where you code, all you need to do is:

1. **Stop** the servers (Apache, MySql etc..)
2. **Go** to your XAMPP directory (where you've installed it)
3. **Rename** the file *htdocs* to *htdocs_default* (that's so you know which one's the original one...)
4. **Create** a new folder called **htdocs**
5. **Store** your PHP scripts here or folders and have fun!

NOTE: To access your workpath in the browser, you just type **localhost** (as usually).

Answer (score 0):

May be it is too late but ...

You can add your menu item by modifying 2 files :
First add your items in the file name [your_langage].php. You will find this file into the directory [xampp_dir]/htdocs/lang/
Into the file (en.php for example), add the navi component you want.
For example, in your case :

```
    $TEXT['navi-course01'] = "Course01";
```

after the line "    $TEXT['navi-phpswitch'] = "PHP Switch";"
Save your file

Secondly, you have to modify the file phpexamples.php into the directory :
[xampp_dir]/htdocs/xampp/navilinks

Add your menu item for example :

```
<a class="n" target="content" onclick="h(this);" href="external/mycourse01dir/index.php"><?php echo $TEXT['navi-course01']; ?></a><br>
```

Save the file, restart your menu eg. http://localhost

If you want this modification in all the languages of your xampp installation, please, you have to modify all the files in the dir lang.

The menu items are shown in the same order they are ordered in the phpexample.php file

Regards